# Replacing symbols and spaces in JS from a filename

Tags: javascript, replace

Original File name: **WhatsApp Image 2021-07-12 at 19.14.09 (4).jpeg**

```
function replaceString(string) {
 return string.replace(/[\-\_\.\+]/ig,' ')
}

var _filname = oFile.name;
var fileName = _filname.substr(0, _filname.lastIndexOf('.'));
$('#title').val(replaceString(fileName));
```

Output: **WhatsApp Image 2021 07 12 at 19 14 09 (4)**

I want **WhatsApp Image at**
(removing digits and symbols ())

I tried:

```
 function replaceString(string) {
 return string.replace(/[-_().]|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0/g,'');
 }
```

I still leaves **spaces** :

```
WhatsApp Image  at
```

I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since between the digits there were spaces, which was not defined in the case, so I used double space to be replaced with single space. and it worked

```
    function replaceString(string) {
        var string = string.replace(/[-_().]|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0/ig,'');
        return string.replace(/  /ig,' ');
    }
```

Comment: You said you wanted the extension gone.

Comment: I did not talk about the EXTENSION GONE I asked I donot want even extensions

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong regex syntax, try replacing with a character class like so:

```js
function replaceString(string) {
    return string.replace(/[^a-z]|jpeg/gi,'');
 }
 
 console.log(replaceString("WhatsApp Image 2021-07-12 at 19.14.09 (4).jpeg"))
```

Comment: using yours, removes WhatsApp at also, i mean it removes everything.

Comment: @RiyaSingh I fixed with a better version, which also trims the file extension.

Comment: Sorry! but What I want is only alphabets, if it is any 0-9 digits or symbols like -,(,),{,} it should be removed and yes I Do Not want extension.

Comment: @RiyaSingh I updated to remove extension as well as numerics/symbols.